# What it the best way to compute Difference data and send it over network?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Well straight to the point, I have two arrays say oldArray[SIZE] and newArray[SIZE]. I want to find the difference between the each element of both arrays eg:

`oldArray[0]-newArray[0] = 
oldArray[1]-newArray[1] = 
oldArray[2]-newArray[2] = 
:
:
oldArray[SIZE]-newArray[SIZE] =`

If the difference is zero no worries but if the diff is >0 store the data along with index. What the best way to store. I want to send this difference data to the client over network. Only ways that I am aware of is using a vector or a dynamic array. I'd really appreciate help with this.

**Update**: oldArray[] and newArra[] are two image frames of a video sequence which have depth values for each pixel, I want to compute the difference between the two frames and send only the difference over the network and on the other end I will again reconstruct the image frame, data is integer range from 0 to 1024. Hope this helps

Comment: What are you trying to do and why does what you have not work?  Are you looking for how to encode the difference or how to apply it? -- then maybe you should try to be specific about that in your question

Comment: You say "Only ways that I am aware of is using a vector or a dynamic array" - that seems like a good solution.  Is there a reason that that wouldn't work?

Comment: Are the values integer, floating point , what?

Comment: I would say compute the full result and store it in an array of vector then take a second pass and either remove the results you don't need(if using a vector) or copy the results you do need into a vector.  The other option would be to have your code compute the result of an index and then copy of you need that value and repeat for the whole array

Comment: what's the question? how to compute an array of differences, or how to send it efficiently across a network?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a `std::map<int,std::pair<T,T>>` where key is the index in question, and the `std::pair` contains the old value in `first` and the new value in `second`. No entries for equal `first` and `second`.

---

As for your edit a `std::map<int,int>` where key is the index, and value is the difference might be sufficient to keep your bitmaps synchronized.

---

How to serialize that properly over the network is a different kettle of fish.

Comment: Right now I guess std::map<int,int> is the best solution thank you for the quick reply

Comment: @vinaydatta Well, it's always better to keep the original information, but I'd suspect your map's value is the difference, so if that's sufficient for you OK. It's of course easier to serialize and saves bandwith.